# Scraping <script> tag with BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and trying to develop a simple web scraper. I am having issues with scraping a script tag within the HTML. Here is my code :

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = "https://yeezysupply.com/products/womens-mule-pvc-clear"

def get_variants():
    url1 = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.28 Safari/537.36'})
    url2 = urlopen(url1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url2, 'html.parser')
    variants = soup.find(string=re.compile(r'\bid\s*:\s(\d{11}),\s*parent_id'))
    print(variants)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_variants()
```

The code currently returns :

```
KANYE.p.variants.push({
  id                : 38844706759,
  parent_id         : 9876888199,
  available         : true,
  featured_image    : null,
  public_title      : null,
  requires_shipping : true,
  price             : 62500,
  options           : ["35"],
  option1           : "35",
  option2           : "",
  option3           : "",
  option4           : ""
});

KANYE.p.variants.push({
  id                : 38844706887,
  parent_id         : 9876888199,
  available         : true,
  featured_image    : "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1765\/5971\/products\/KW3029.001_Side1_650xx.jpg?v=1488326253",
  public_title      : null,
  requires_shipping : true,
  price             : 62500,
  options           : ["35.5"],
  option1           : "35.5",
  option2           : "",
  option3           : "",
  option4           : ""
});

KANYE.p.variants.push({
  id                : 38844706951,
  parent_id         : 9876888199,
  available         : true,
  featured_image    : null,
  public_title      : null,
  requires_shipping : true,
  price             : 62500,
  options           : ["36"],
  option1           : "36",
  option2           : "",
  option3           : "",
  option4           : ""
});
...
```

I'm trying to only scrape "id" and its value. So I need to scrape id: 38844706759, id: 38844706887, id: 38844706951. How is this possible? I've been at this for quite some time and I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup can't parse script tags. Only find text that matches your query inside them (Because they are a part of a top level element.).

After your `variants = soup.find(string=re.compile(r'\bid\s*:\s(\d{11}),\s*parent_id'))` you can do a regex findall to find the ID tags.

```
variants = soup.find_all(string=re.compile(r'\bid\s*:\s(\d{11}),\s*parent_id'))
for variant in variants:
    print (re.findall(r'id\s+:.(.*?),', variant,  re.MULTILINE))
```

Which outputs

```
[u'9876888199', u'38844706759', u'9876888199'...]
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for your response. I tried to implement that code and it returned `[]` countless times and not the id's. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @BrianHunt update your variants find with the code that I updated my post with;

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Is there a way to only output id and not the parent_id?